# Linking error including Random Number Library in C++ AMP

Tags: random, c++-amp, directcompute

I am using the [C++ AMP tinymt library](https://amprng.codeplex.com) from [Codeplex](https://amprng.codeplex.com) to generate random numbers. The library works fine, except that when I `#include <amp_tinymt_rng.h>` in two different files in the same project, linking errors arise mentioning redefintion of certain variables **tinymt_lib::tinymt_dc_data** and **tinymt_dc_data_32**.

What would be a good fix to get rid of this issue, given that I am using `#pragma once` in every header already?
I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

As a side suggestion, what would be a simpler way to generate random numbers without the overhead of a special library? I am not concerned about the sequence not being safely random, a simple `random()` or `rand()` be suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error in the way the library is written. It seems like the headers are fragile if included more than once. I'd suggest that you start a thread on the [Parallel Computing in C++ and Native Code forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=parallelcppnative).

Comment: I had reported the issue on Codeplex on the same day as this question was posted, and it got fixed 3 days later. :)